# Do I really have to install the bundler 1.0.0.beta.3 to run the latest edge rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

When I do `bundle install` bundling edge rails I get this error:

```
No compatible versions could be found for required dependencies:
    Conflict on: "bundler":
    * bundler (0.9.26) activated by bundler (= 0.9.26, runtime)
    * bundler (>= 1.0.0.beta.3, runtime) required by rails (>= 0, runtime)
    All possible versions of origin requirements conflict.
```

Is there any way that I can install the lastest edge rails without installing bundler 1.0.0.beta.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On July 1st the Bundler dependency in edge Rails was bumped from 0.9.26 to 1.0.0.beta.2 (and each subsequent beta over the past weeks). As far as I know, edge Rails is still fully compatible with 0.9.26, so you should be able to edit [rails.gemspec](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/rails.gemspec) to read:

```
s.add_dependency('bundler', '>= 0.9.26')
```

I have already done this for 3 projects on edge rails, because they are deployed on Heroku which is still running Bundler 0.9.26. I've not had any issues or broken tests.